# Camshaft position sensor low input on Hyundai Accent 2008

Tags: sensor

Hi I have a no start on this car. It drove home fine then wouldn't start the next day. Timing, battery, starter, relays, fuses, immobilizer, spark and fuel all check out fine but code is p0342 for camshaft sensor and I've even tried a new one to no avail so I tested the harness/wires and negative is about 2.5 ohms and positive is 12.5 volts but signal is 11.7 volts. It's close but I'm wondering if anyone can tell me if this is causing a no start issue through my sensor?

Comment: If you hook your meter to battery positive and probe the sensor ground do you have battery voltage? When you crank the engine what kind of reading do you get on the signal wire?